# My OpenID works on Stack Overflow, but not on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: support, jobs, login, openid

I can log into Stack Overflow using my OpenID (tried on Firefox), but using the *same* OpenID in Stack Overflow [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers), I get the folowing error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

I've tried both on Firefox and Chromium, and had the same result in both browsers. What amazes me, is that I can log out/log in from Stack Overflow, but not Stack Overflow Careers.

Have I found a bug?

And yes; I've copy-pasted the OpenID URL in both cases, and have tried **several** times, so I'm not mistyping.

Comment: Even though my issue is fixed, I'm sure lots of people will be lured here with the exact same symptoms, but different cause. If you have an answer that might help those people, I'd suggest you still post them here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you already logged in?  The only time I encountered that error was when I was already logged in (and I use MyOpenID).  In fact I just logged in, tried to log in again, and got the same error.

That's sort of a bug in itself, though....

Comment: No, I wasn't logged in; as I said, I even tried installing an alternate browser.

Comment: Magically, I got home from the university, and I'm logged in. This does not even explain why this also failed on an alternate browser. This thing is haunted. :/